# Преобразование в base64 и отправка на сервер , подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать?

Tags: react-native, expo

Получаем фото -> преобразуем его в base64 -> отправляем на сервер.
Помогите пожалуйста в реализации такого функционала.
Работаю через react native expo. Я знаю что в expo imagepicker есть встроенный метод который преобразует в base64, я его и использую. Но я не уверен что он отрабатывает правильно(может посоветуете альтернативу.
Ниже прилагаю код преобразования изображения и отправки на сервер (этот код не работает ) помогите разобраться в чем проблема ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что именно не работает-то? какой ответ сервера, какие данные отправляются?

Comment: Возможно стоит отказаться от передачи изображения в виде base64, Вы знаете что он тяжелее на 37% чем обычный файл ?